# Search and replace string in a very big file

Tags: json, perl, awk, large-files, data-manipulation

I have a preference for shell commands to get things done. I have a very, very big file -- about 2.8 GB and the content is that of JSON. Everything is on one line, and I was told there are at least 1.5 million records in there.

I must prepare the file for consumption. Each record must be on its own line. Sample:

```
{"RomanCharacters":{"Alphabet":[{"RecordId":"1",...]},{"RecordId":"2",...},{"RecordId":"3",...},{"RecordId":"4",...},{"RecordId":"5",...} }}
```

Or, use the following...

```
{"Accounts":{"Customer":[{"AccountHolderId":"9c585258-c94c-442b-a2f0-1ebbcc274795","Title":"Mrs","Forename":"Tina","Surname":"Wright","DateofBirth":"1988-01-01","Contact":[{"Contact_Info":"9168777943","TypeId":"Mobile Number","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"1","Superseded":"No" },{"Contact_Info":"9503588153","TypeId":"Home Telephone","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Index":"2","Superseded":"Yes" },{"Contact_Info":"acne.pimple@microchimerism.com","TypeId":"Email Address","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"3","Superseded":"No" },{"Contact_Info":"swati.singh@microchimerism.com","TypeId":"Email Address","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Index":"4","Superseded":"Yes" }, {"Contact_Info":"christian.bale@hollywood.com","TypeId":"Email Address","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"5","Superseded":"NO" },{"Contact_Info":"15482475584","TypeId":"Mobile_Phone","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"6","Superseded":"No" }],"Address":[{"AddressPtr":"5","Line1":"Flat No.14","Line2":"Surya Estate","Line3":"Baner","Line4":"Pune ","Line5":"new","Addres_City":"pune","Country":"India","PostCode":"AB100KP","PrimaryFlag":"No","Superseded":"No"},{"AddressPtr":"6","Line1":"A-602","Line2":"Viva Vadegiri","Line3":"Virar","Line4":"new","Line5":"banglow","Addres_City":"Mumbai","Country":"India","PostCode":"AB10V6T","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Superseded":"Yes"}],"Account":[{"Field_A":"6884133655531279","Field_B":"887.07","Field_C":"A Loan Product",...,"FieldY_":"2015-09-18","Field_Z":"24275627"}]},{"AccountHolderId":"92a5788f-cd8f-423d-ae5f-4eb0ceb457fd","_Title":"Dr","_Forename":"Christopher","_Surname":"Carroll","_DateofBirth":"1977-02-02","Contact":[{"Contact_Info":"9168777943","TypeId":"Mobile Number","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"7","Superseded":"No" },{"Contact_Info":"9503588153","TypeId":"Home Telephone","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Index":"8","Superseded":"Yes" },{"Contact_Info":"acne.pimple@microchimerism.com","TypeId":"Email Address","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"9","Superseded":"No" },{"Contact_Info":"swati.singh@microchimerism.com","TypeId":"Email Address","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Index":"10","Superseded":"Yes" }],"Address":[{"AddressPtr":"11","Line1":"Flat No.14","Line2":"Surya Estate","Line3":"Baner","Line4":"Pune ","Line5":"new","Addres_City":"pune","Country":"India","PostCode":"AB11TXF","PrimaryFlag":"No","Superseded":"No"},{"AddressPtr":"12","Line1":"A-602","Line2":"Viva Vadegiri","Line3":"Virar","Line4":"new","Line5":"banglow","Addres_City":"Mumbai","Country":"India","PostCode":"AB11O8W","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Superseded":"Yes"}],"Account":[{"Field_A":"4121879819185553","Field_B":"887.07","Field_C":"A Loan Product",...,"Field_X":"2015-09-18","Field_Z":"25679434"}]},{"AccountHolderId":"4aa10284-d9aa-4dc0-9652-70f01d22b19e","_Title":"Dr","_Forename":"Cheryl","_Surname":"Ortiz","_DateofBirth":"1977-03-03","Contact":[{"Contact_Info":"9168777943","TypeId":"Mobile Number","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"13","Superseded":"No" },{"Contact_Info":"9503588153","TypeId":"Home Telephone","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Index":"14","Superseded":"Yes" },{"Contact_Info":"acne.pimple@microchimerism.com","TypeId":"Email Address","PrimaryFlag":"No","Index":"15","Superseded":"No" },{"Contact_Info":"swati.singh@microchimerism.com","TypeId":"Email Address","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Index":"16","Superseded":"Yes" }],"Address":[{"AddressPtr":"17","Line1":"Flat No.14","Line2":"Surya Estate","Line3":"Baner","Line4":"Pune ","Line5":"new","Addres_City":"pune","Country":"India","PostCode":"AB12SQR","PrimaryFlag":"No","Superseded":"No"},{"AddressPtr":"18","Line1":"A-602","Line2":"Viva Vadegiri","Line3":"Virar","Line4":"new","Line5":"banglow","Addres_City":"Mumbai","Country":"India","PostCode":"AB12BAQ","PrimaryFlag":"Yes","Superseded":"Yes"}],"Account":[{"Field_A":"3288214945919484","Field_B":"887.07","Field_C":"A Loan Product",...,"Field_Y":"2015-09-18","Field_Z":"66264768"}]}]}}
```

Final outcome should be:

```
{"RomanCharacters":{"Alphabet":[{"RecordId":"1",...]},
{"RecordId":"2",...},
{"RecordId":"3",...},
{"RecordId":"4",...},
{"RecordId":"5",...} }}
```

Attempted commands:

- `sed -e 's/,{"RecordId"/}]},\n{"RecordId"/g' sample.dat`
- `awk '{gsub(",{\"RecordId\"",",\n{\"RecordId\"",$0); print $0}' sample.dat`

The attempted commands works perfectly fine for small files. But it does not work for the 2.8 GB file that I must manipulate. Sed quits midway after 10 mins without reason and nothing was done. Awk errored with a Segmentation Fault (core dump) reason after many hours in. I tried perl's search and replace and got an error saying "Out of memory".

Any help/ ideas would be great!

Additional info on my machine:

- More than 105 GB disk space available.
- 8 GB memory
- 4 cores CPU
- Running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: We need some better sample data - doesn't have to be a dump of your data, but illustrative of the problem at hand. Also - have you considered using a parser?

Comment: The basic problem, I think, is that all 3 of those tools read line-at-a-time and thus get hosed by the "single huge line". Try pre-processing first with something like `tr ',' '\012'` to replace commas with newlines. Then the line-at-a-time tools will work better.

Comment: Try again with perl but set $/ to ",". Also try the "-u" parameter for sed (--unbuffered).

Comment: The proper fix would be to show us the Awk and Perl programs you used, and help us help you fix them.

Comment: My perl level is, admittedly, beginner. But the perl mentioned can be found here -- http://pastebin.com/8EeXmbMT . How should I modify with your suggestion? Willing to try everything so long as it works!

Comment: Your sample data is not valid JSON. Please include something closer to real data for testing.

Comment: I have added a valid JSON. If you find and delete the following "..." (without quotes), then you will have a valid one.

Comment: Trivial problem: your Pastebin link shows code which reads the entire file into memory before processing it. Using a custom record separator - like in @choroba's answer, but perhaps with more frills - would allow you to process the file piecemeal.

Comment: @dat789 ... ick. When I suggested [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34993192/1072112) that you could use perl, I didn't mean that you should use it like sed. I was referring to things like [`decode_json()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#decode_json). If you're in a language that can actually understand your data structure, then use those tools!

Comment: Your example desired output has some major braces issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding perl: Try setting the input line separator `$/` to `},` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$/= "},"; 
while (<>){
   print "$_\n"; 
}'
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
$ perl -e '$/="},";while(<>){print "$_\n"}' sample.dat
```

Comment: This has proven to work swiftly. I have modified your script to have found the solution to the problem. I will share it shortly.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at the `-n` and `-p` flags. I think you could write that as: `perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/="},"} print "\n"; }`

Answer (score 4):

Since you've tagged your question with sed, awk AND perl, I gather that what you really need is a recommendation for a tool.  While that's kind of off-topic, I believe that [*jq*](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is something you could use for this. It will be better than sed or awk because it actually *understands JSON*. Everything shown here with jq could also be done in perl with a bit of programming.

Assuming content like the following (based on your sample):

```
{"RomanCharacters":{"Alphabet": [ {"RecordId":"1","data":"data"},{"RecordId":"2","data":"data"},{"RecordId":"3","data":"data"},{"RecordId":"4","data":"data"},{"RecordId":"5","data":"data"} ] }}
```

You can easily reformat this to "prettify" it:

```
$ jq '.' < data.json
{
  "RomanCharacters": {
    "Alphabet": [
      {
        "RecordId": "1",
        "data": "data"
      },
      {
        "RecordId": "2",
        "data": "data"
      },
      {
        "RecordId": "3",
        "data": "data"
      },
      {
        "RecordId": "4",
        "data": "data"
      },
      {
        "RecordId": "5",
        "data": "data"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And we can dig in to the data to retrieve only the records you're interested in (regardless of what they're wrapped in):

```
$ jq '.[][][]' < data.json
{
  "RecordId": "1",
  "data": "data"
}
{
  "RecordId": "2",
  "data": "data"
}
{
  "RecordId": "3",
  "data": "data"
}
{
  "RecordId": "4",
  "data": "data"
}
{
  "RecordId": "5",
  "data": "data"
}
```

This is much more readable, both by humans and by tools like awk which process content line-by-line.  If you want to join your lines for processing per your question, the awk becomes much more simple:

```
$ jq '.[][][]' < data.json | awk '{printf("%s ",$0)} /}/{printf("\n")}'
{   "RecordId": "1",   "data": "data" }
{   "RecordId": "2",   "data": "data" }
{   "RecordId": "3",   "data": "data" }
{   "RecordId": "4",   "data": "data" }
{   "RecordId": "5",   "data": "data" }
```

Or, as @peak suggested in comments, eliminate the `awk` portion of thie entirely by using jq's `-c` (compact output) option:

```
$ jq -c '.[][][]' < data.json
{"RecordId":"1","data":"data"}
{"RecordId":"2","data":"data"}
{"RecordId":"3","data":"data"}
{"RecordId":"4","data":"data"}
{"RecordId":"5","data":"data"}
```

Comment: Note that jq's -c option can be used to advantage here.  In the example using data.json, `jq -c '.[][][]' < data.json` produces the results obtained above using `awk` as a post-processor.  In fact, I suspect that if we had a better idea of what the OP is trying to accomplish, the whole thing could easily be done in jq quite economically.

Comment: @peak - brilliant, thank you for that, for some reason that never occurred to me.  :-)  I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `}` as the record separator, e.g. in Perl:

```
perl -l -0175 -ne 'print $_, $/' < input
```

You might need to glue back lines containing only `}`.

Answer (score 2):

This avoids the memory problem by not looking at the data as a single record, but may go too far the other way with respect to performance (processing a single character at a time). Also note that it requires gawk for the built-in `RT` variable (value of the current record separator):

```
$ cat j.awk
BEGIN { RS="[[:print:]]" }
RT == "{" { bal++}
RT == "}" { bal-- }
{ printf "%s", RT }
RT == "," && bal == 2 { print "" }
END { print "" }

$ gawk -f j.awk j.txt
{"RomanCharacters":{"Alphabet":[{"RecordId":"1",...]},
{"RecordId":"2",...},
{"RecordId":"3",...},
{"RecordId":"4",...},
{"RecordId":"5",...} }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data provided here (the one that begins with {Accounts:{Customer... ), the solution to this problem is one that reads in the file and as it is reading it is counting the number of delimiters defined in $/. For every count of 10,000 delimiters, it will write out to a new file. And for each delimiter found, it gives it a new line. Here is how the script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$base="/home/dat789/incoming";
#$_="sample.dat";

$/= "}]},";   # delimiter to find and insert new line after
$n = 0;
$match="";
$filecount=0;
$recsPerFile=10000;   # set number of records in a file

print "Processing " . $_ ."\n";

while (<>){
   if ($n < $recsPerFile) {
      $match=$match.$_."\n";
      $n++;
      print "."; #This is so that we'd know it has done something
   }    
   else {
      my $newfile="partfile".$recsPerFile."-".$filecount . ".dat";
      open ( OUTPUT,'>', $newfile );
      print OUTPUT $match;
      $match="";
      $filecount++;   
      $n=0;
     print "Wrote file " .  $newfile . "\n";
   }
}

print "Finished\n\n";
```

I've used this script against the big 2.8 GB file where it's content is an unformatted one-liner JSON. The resulting output files would be missing the correct JSON headers and footers but this can be easily fixed.

Thank you so much guys for contributing!